# Spring Boot - entityManagerFactory cannot be found

Tags: java, spring

I know that this question has been asked for a number of times on SO, but I tried all the suggestions and none of them worked.

I want to create a REST controller, and a data source to connect to a mysql db instance. But when I start my spring boot app, I get this error:

When I add `@EnableJPARepositories` to my data source configuration class, the error changes to:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.boot.myproject.investment.repository.MyRepository' in your configuration.
```

This is the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repo;

    //....
}
```

My data source configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

`application.properties`:

```
app.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myAppDB
app.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
app.datasource.username=root
app.datasource.password=
```

The entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MyEntity")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

}
```

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

`build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.0.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', version: '2.5.0'
    compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1' 
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '2.0.9.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version:'5.1.44'  
}
```

I tried several different ways:

1. I tried refreshing the project both from the CL (./gradlew --refresh-dependencies), and from eclipse.
2. Made sure there's no hibernate related dependency in my gradle
3. Tried `BasicDataSource` instead of `DataSource`:

   BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
4. Tried `@Transactional` instead of `@Repository` to annotate the repo class, although I don't think it's related.

I'm wondering what is wrong with my config, that it gives me such error.

Comment: Remove `spring-webmvc`, `javax.servlet-api` and replace with `spring-boot-starter-web` . Remove the `javax.persistence-api` and `spring-data-jpa` and replace with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. I would also suggest removing `commons-dbcp2` and use the default HikariCP instead.

Comment: I had to change `app.datasource.url` with `app.datasource.jdbc-url`, too.

Comment: Remove the DatasourceConfiguration as well and name your configs spring.datasource.*

Comment: @M.Deinum how come having/removing `@Repository` has no effect? is it auto-detected? should I keep `@Repository`?

Comment: An `@Component` annotation (like `@repository`) on an interface is useless. Spring Data uses different mechanisms to find `Repository` (the interface) extending interfaces.

Comment: You don't need @Repository because Spring Data JPA is generating the Repository class on runtime.

Comment: Maybe you should start by reading the Getting Started Guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ and then the Reference Documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

I have a *very* similar configuration, the only difference is that I have a `LocalContainerEntitymanagerFactoryBean` in my `DatasourceConfiguration`.

In addition to the other comments, add something like this:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory( DataSource dataSource )
{
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource( dataSource );
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan( MyEntity.class.getPackage().getName() );
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter( new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter() );
    return entityManagerFactory;
}
```